# accessing a route directly from browser in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel-5, routes, laravel-5.3

I have a checkout link for my locally developing e-commerce website as 'http://autohub.com/checkout/120000' where '12000' is the cart total. It is working perfectly whenever i go to the cart and go to checkout from there. But the thing is if i type the above link directly in the browser then the checkout page is accessible again. I need to stop doing so. Thanks in advance.
my web.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
Route::get('/checkout/{price}','searchController@getCheckout');
```

});

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can check the [HTTP_REFERER](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_server):

```
Request::server('HTTP_REFERER')
```

& make sure it is NOT null or it is a URL in the same domain.